# Extend local network DNS in VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, routing, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN configuration, that pulls all routes from the server and then routes everything through that Gateway. This is causing me trouble since the connection is sometimes extremely slow and I want to use a server `coruscant` on my local network as a Docker- and CI-Server. I've managed to limit these routings by resetting the default route:

**Before connecting to the vpn:**

```bsh
$ netstat -rn | head
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.178.1      UGScg          en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0
```

**After connecting to the vpn:**

```bsh
$ netstat -rn | head
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            10.106.176.1       UGScg        utun4
10                 10.106.176.1       UGSc         utun4
10.106.176/22      10.106.176.6       UGSc         utun4
10.106.176.6       10.106.176.6       UH           utun4
80.85.192/20       10.106.176.1       UGSc         utun4
...

# Reroute through local router
$ route delete default && route add default 192.168.178.1
```

My router is available at `fritz.box` and after adding its ip to `/etc/hosts`, it is also available when connected to the VPN. My router uses DHCP and my local server `coruscant` may change its ip - won't it??

Therefore I am unsure how to make it available when I am connected to the VPN. Is there any way to attach my local network to be resolvable?